# How do I put woocommerce cart page to my checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want my cart page to show up on my checkout page. And I want to remove the order review from checkout page. so my cart page will show on the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
To remove order review from checkout page...
```

In your plugin folder Go To woocommerce->includes->wc-template-functions.php Now press ctrl+f and write woocommerce_order_review and press enter. You will find a function of the same name. Just remove its body(portion that comes under{}) And its done.

```
To show cart page and checkout page on sigle custom page
```

you can use shortcode *[woocommerce_cart]* for cart and *[woocommerce_checkout]* for checkout on a custom page.Use both shortcode on a single page that might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the solution to the first part of your question:

- Goto WooCommerce Settings->Checkout
- Under Checkout Pages section set Cart Page dropdown to Checkout
- Now anytime shopper hits the cart button they go straight to checkout

Comment: But i want my cart table to show up my checkout page. So my cart table on the top and then contact information. And I want to remove "review order" table since I will have my cart table on the top.

Comment: Is that possible? Can you help me with that?